# How to apply correlation to specified vectors, iterating through list of files?

Tags: r

I need to take a list of dataframes and apply cor() to the same two columns in each, returning a list of correlation values. The following is my function so far:

```
 corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){

 #reads directory of files

         file_list <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/jonah/Documents/R work/R Coursera Course/specdata")



 # takes file_list and makes each file into dataframe

         dflist <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)



 # returns list of files, na rows stripped

         nolist <- lapply(dflist, na.omit)

 # removes all with nrows < threshold

         abovelist <- nolist[sapply(nolist, function(x) nrow(x) > threshold)]

          

 # runs correlation of nitrate, sulfate on remaining
         correlations <- lapply(abovelist, cor(abovelist$sulfate, abovelist$nitrate))

 }
```

Each of the dataframes has four columns: a Date, a sulfate amount, a nitrate amount, and an ID column. All that I care about are sulfate and nitrate (and their correlation). How do I set up lapply to work on those columns?

Thank you in advance.

Each

Comment: Just a hint for finding lots of previous discussions on these Coursera questions - https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20pollutant

Comment: I think "pollutantmean" is the keyword https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+pollutantmean . Although I think this question is different from the "pollutantmean" ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function in `lapply` to refer to the object, the same way you did for `sapply`.

Try this :

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){
  file_list <- list.files(path = directory)
  dflist <- lapply(file_list, function(x) na.omit(read.csv(x)))
  abovelist <- dflist[sapply(dflist, nrow) > threshold]
  correlations <- lapply(abovelist, function(x) cor(x$sulfate, x$nitrate))
  return(correlations)
}
```

and call this as :

```
corr("C:/Users/jonah/Documents/R work/R Coursera Course/specdata")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I appreciate the help greatly.